# Let's get critical: Aug 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Blender Stack Exchange](http://blender.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://blender.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Final Results

- [What is the order of transformations when exporting to Collada?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1806/what-is-the-order-of-transformations-when-exporting-to-collada)

  **Net Score: 9** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [How can I control the viewport without a mouse?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1511/how-can-i-control-the-viewport-without-a-mouse)

  **Net Score: 9** (Excellent: 10, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [How to make lamp visible to camera in cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1677/how-to-make-lamp-visible-to-camera-in-cycles)

  **Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [Baking AO and Shadows into one image?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1848/baking-ao-and-shadows-into-one-image)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Can I confirm knife action with mouse, or other key than Enter?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1630/can-i-confirm-knife-action-with-mouse-or-other-key-than-enter)

  **Net Score: 10** (Excellent: 10, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Is there a post-finish operator hook in the python API](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1568/is-there-a-post-finish-operator-hook-in-the-python-api)

  **Net Score: 9** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [is it possible to make a setting enabled by default?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1921/is-it-possible-to-make-a-setting-enabled-by-default)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Visual programming with Blender Python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1679/visual-programming-with-blender-python)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [Console vs scripting python constants](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1896/console-vs-scripting-python-constants)

  **Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Can I use an image sequence with offset frames as a texture on array items](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1911/can-i-use-an-image-sequence-with-offset-frames-as-a-texture-on-array-items)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 3)