# How serious is the 'self -evaluation'

Tags: discussion

it doesn't seem to have attracted much attention in the meta, where does kind of post come from and does it have any effect on B.SE.

I feel a bit of a chump being the only person who added to the discussion in [Let's get critical](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265/lets-get-critical-aug-2013-site-self-evaluation)

Comment: [You don't normally answer these..](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166397/can-we-see-the-results-of-our-community-evaluation/166701#166701). Insight is good but not a must, it is an automated process that we get to do as a community every (n) days or so (90 _IIRC_, not sure). Example on [meta.fitness.se](http://meta.fitness.stackexchange.com/q/466) and example on [meta.anime.se](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/672/lets-get-critical-aug-2013-site-self-evaluation). After the eval ends, the results will be posted by Community.

Comment: hey, I won't bother in future.